# Hi PHP Version 5.3.0 upgrade to 5.5.9

Tags: php

How to solve the &= Error deprecation after upgrading php version from 5.3 to 5.5.9  the i try to resolve the error depricatation by removing the "&" on &= the it works it did not display error but the second problem i encounter is some of the function is not working the call back of the function on the login process did not work does the upgrade of php version is the problem how tofix this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by understanding what the original code is really doing. Just removing part of the operator will change the meaning of the code and you shouldn't be surprised that the code fails in some areas.

The line

```
$a &= $b;
```

Really means `perform a bitwise AND operation with $a and $b; assign the result to $a`

It's equivalent to:

```
$a = $a & $b;
```

Comment: Yes sir so does it means that i need to recode this?

Comment: Out of curiosity I looked for something that says the `&=` operator is deprecated. Not only could I not find any mention in the PHP migration notes, I couldn't replicate the message on my development system (PHP 5.5.13). My answer is good for your question, but I'm not sure you've asked the right question.